# Creating a touch screen driver for OS X: where to start?

Tags: c, macos, driver, multi-touch, kernel-module

OK, so I recently purchased an [Acer T232HL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00966IW72) touch screen display to hook up to my Macbook Pro as a secondary monitor. To give you an idea, [here's my setup](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BOSFFeJCAAA0bdt.jpg:large).

OS X doesn't support this monitor in any way, so as you can see in the screenshot I'm actually running Windows 8 through VMware, which proxies the USB connection to Windows perfectly where the touch events are supported. But obviously this isn't ideal.

There's [at least one](http://www.touch-base.com) 3rd party driver for OS X that looked sort of promising, but it doesn't seem to support multitouch from this device, it's expensive, and generally was a pain to get working to the small degree it was. There's also [mt4j](http://www.mt4j.org/) but best I could tell after running their examples, it doesn't support this device at all.

So here's my question: what exactly am I in for if I wanted to write a driver for this thing? I'm mostly a web developer with years of experience with Ruby, Objective-C (and a little C), Javascript, etc. I have never ventured into any kind of hardware programming, so from the surface this feels like an interesting while intimidating challenge.

I know at some level I need to read data from USB. I know this will probably mean trying to reverse engineer whatever protocol they're using for the touch events (is it possible this will be entirely custom?). However I haven't got a clue where to start - would this be a kernel extension? In C, I presume? Would love a high level overview of the moving parts involved here.

Ultimately I want to use the touch screen to drive a specialized web interface (running in Chrome), so ideally I could proxy the touch events straight to Chrome without the OS actually moving the mouse cursor to the touch location (so have the UI behave just as it would on an iPad), but regardless of whether this is technically possible, I'd love to start with just getting something working.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Looks like single-finger works a bit better on El Capitan (10.11.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to start with Apple's [I/O Kit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html). You can hope that the touchscreen isn't completely custom, though there must be some part that's not standard USB HID, or it would work already. If there are any linux (or other open source) drivers available, you'll have the advantage that somebody already did some of the reverse engineering for you.  As an alternative to the I/O Kit, you might also want to look into [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/), which might make your brain hurt less when getting started.  If you end up needing to write a kext, that might not help you anymore, though.

As to some of your specific questions:

> would this be a kernel extension?

Maybe, maybe not.  I'm not really up on the Mac OS X driver situation, but I did write some totally user-space USB code for OS X many years ago.  Maybe you'll be as lucky.

> In C, I presume?

Probably.  I/O Kit itself is written in a subset of C++, so you can probably use that too, if you prefer.

> is it possible this will be entirely custom?

Unfortunately, yes, it's possible.

Good luck!

Comment: A perfect answer - I now have a place to start. Thanks, Carl!

Comment: Did you have any luck? I don't get why OSX has to be so troublesome as I always thought, the touch pointing used the same protocol as the mouse and thus one could simply connect the screen by USB and done with it... I also want to get the Acer T232HL for a Mac Pro.... Thanks for any help.

Comment: Aha: check this out: just as I thought: http://www.amazon.com/support-win-Mac-VM-Mac-win-8-1/forum/Fx1MMROB4KNSDC1/Tx2E3IL9Z7A2P3T/1/ref=cm_cd_ql_tlc_al?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00I2P6TEG